# How to make table's width fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I have two tables inside a table :

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tdkqtb">
                    <table border="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Giải</th>
                                <th>@cityID</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>

                <td class="tdkqtb">
                    <table border="1">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Đầu</th>
                                <th>Đuôi</th>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr></tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

[image]

Now I need to set the width of the two tables fixed. How can I do that? For example I want all tables to have the same width as the first twos. I mean they must have a fixed width for each column, the first table will contains 70% width of the parent table, and the second contains the rest. The columns in the two tables must have fixed width too!

Comment: So what *should* the widths be? Your code shows just one table containing two simple tables, not code that actually generates the image shown. Although the idea can be inferred, the question is exactly how the widths should be set. What should the fixed widths be, and what should the parent table width be? Showing your attempt at achieving that, in addition to describing it in words, would greatly help in seeing what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood what you want but you can just select the required element of the table or the whole table and give a width in css

```
table {
    width: 70%;
}
```

If you have multiple tables, give them ids or classes to seperate for different styles. Same for the th, tr, td and so on.

Comment: I gave the parent table 100% Width, and 70% to the first table, 30% to the second and it seems doesn't work very well!

Comment: Why is there a gap between the two tables?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8m4sw1o3/
check out this snippet. Not sure if its what you want but I would suggest creating two separate tables.

Comment: perfect, I didn't realize we have to set the td's width, by the way what do you mean by two table separately? Does that mean we don't need a parent table to "cover"\ them?

Comment: Well I mean why would you put two tables in a table. You can simply create two tables side by side.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why not going [Tableless](http://www.w3.org/2002/03/csslayout-howto.html.en)?

Then you have to put some CSS into it, like DasBoot said, to give a full table a width you should do this:

```
table {
    width: 70%;
}
```

The same thing for specific td, tr, th or whatever element you want to style. If what you are going for is a maximum width or a minimum width you can use `max-width` and `min-width` appropriately. Why not put this code on a jsfiddle and test the results live to see what you need to do?

Regards.

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked. Besides, suggesting non-table approach to data that is apparently tabular is poor advocacy.